# Renewing gpg key "secret key parts are not available"

Tags: gnupg

Running gpg 1.4 and last year I setup a key to use with aptly.

The key has now expired and I can't seem to renew. Tried all sorts of things and not getting anywhere, partly because I set it up a year ago.

```
gpg --edit-key C8FF59B8

Secret key is available.

pub  4096R/C8FF59B8  created: 2017-12-03  expires: never       usage: SC  
                 trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
sub  4096R/30F7AC50  created: 2017-12-03  expires: never       usage: E   
sub  4096R/8C015D46  created: 2017-12-03  expired: 2018-12-03  usage: S   
[ultimate] (1). Name <email>
```

So I can see my key 8C015D46 expired today. 
Then I tried

```
key 2
expire
```

and chose 1y. I get:

```
gpg: secret key parts are not available
gpg: make_keysig_packet failed: general error
```

From what I've read its something to do with master key being offline. I've got the private key saved offline, how do I go about renewing the key?

```
gpg --list-keys
/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------
pub   4096R/C8FF59B8 2017-12-03
uid                  Name <email>
sub   4096R/30F7AC50 2017-12-03
```

List of secret keys

```
gpg --list-secret-key 8C015D46
sec#  4096R/C8FF59B8 2017-12-03
uid                  Name <email>
ssb   4096R/30F7AC50 2017-12-03
ssb   4096R/8C015D46 2017-12-03 [expires: 2018-12-03]
```

Comment: I am not a GnuPG expert, but I guess you should re-import your primary key before changing expiration date of any of your subkeys.

Comment: Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177291/how-to-renew-an-expired-keypair-with-gpg) thread. I believe this should help you.